# TFS 2008 - Users cannot upload files in project portal site

Tags: tfs, wss-3.0, user-permissions

We have TFS 2008 installation for good 5 years and was stable until some thing bad happened. I used TFS BPA to fix the project creation issue and now there are no errors in event log.
But non administrator users cannot upload files from Visual Studio's project portal site. Same users can upload documents to same folder via WSS 3.0 SharePoint site.

I have checked all the permissions for each user and groups, also tried them to add as individual user on project portal site as contributors. I can see all users in Administrative tool have correct rights.

Does anybody have any clue what would have happened? and where to start digging?

Thx Sanjay

Comment: When you say "Visual Studio's project portal site" are you talking about the "Documents" folder that shows up under the Team Project in the Team Explorer?

Comment: Hi Derek, Yes, documents folder(s) available in VS and part of SharePoint Site lists collection.